# How come XHP can alter PHP syntax and yet be wholly implemented as an extension?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xhp

I think what I'm asking is this:

1. To make PHP understand `$a=<div>{$stuff}</div>` one must *alter* the PHP parser
2. The above can *not* be done in a PHP extension or even a Zend extension. To introduce new syntax one has to modify the Zend Engine.
3. XHP does (1) as a simple extension !

What am I missing ?

Comment: Perhaps looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/xhp) for xhp will give you the answer; but there are certainly other PHP extensions that alter the parser such as xhprof, xdebug, runkit, scream, etc.... so your #2 statement is flawed

Comment: Note that the Zend engine isn't the only engine capable of running PHP: hhvm, quercus, IBM's old Project Zero are all alternatives

Comment: @MarkBaker The mentioned extensions change the PHP behaviour and the way predefined functions act but non alters the PHP syntax in any ways as far as I know. Can you kindly give some examples ?

Comment: @MarkBaker Interesting point, you think xhp is an extension for hhvm rather than zend ?

Comment: No, xhp is a perfectly valid PHP extension, so it should work with the Zend engine, or with Quercus or HHVM. I was merely pointing out that there were a couple of flaws in your second argument.... from a cursory look at xhp, it appears to be acting as a PHP pre-processor; but there are other PHP extensions such as xdebug that do affect the parser directly

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the quick response. Yet again I'm having difficulty finding concrete examples showing xdebug affecting PHP syntax (*not* its behaviour). By the waym what is a PHP pre-processor ?

Comment: A pre-processor (in this case) is something that takes your basic xhp code and converts it to straight PHP code before passing it on to the lexer

Comment: An example of a post-processor would be something like APC, wincache or OpCache that takes the results of the lexer/parser cycle and stores them in cache

Comment: Examples of an extension that changes PHP behaviour would be runkit, which allows PHP core functions to be overridden

Comment: I suspect that the only elements of PHP that would require a true change to the parser itself would be control structures; but consider that OpCache manipulates the actual bytecode generated by the parser, so even that can be changed by extensions

Comment: @MarkBaker I understand your point but does this mean that another lexer scans the file first and somehow extracts some parts (perhaps according to some plug-able syntax definition) and only then the actual PHP lexer comes in ?

Comment: That's my basic take on it, after a cursory scan through the source code

Comment: @MarkBaker Say I want to add a new operator with some semantics behind it : `1 in [1,2] // true `, `3 in [1,2] // false`. This can be done purely in extensions ?

Comment: The xhp method would be to take that syntax and convert it to standard PHP syntax before passing it to the lexer, so that would be possible

Comment: But operators and control structures are handled directly by the VM engine, so that's something which couldn't be done easily

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are elements supported by the engine that aren't implemented in PHP syntax, I recently discovered that the engine itself already supports return type hinting (available in hack, and recently proposed as an RFC for PHP)